# Junk in the terminal when trying to export .png

Tags: gnuplot

I have a file (called `print_1012720.txt`) that looks like the text shown below.

```
1133254688 5698771509078629376
1150031904 5698771509371165696
1150031904 5698771510035551232
4170258464 5698771510036082688
2895583264 5698771510036715520
1620908064 5698771510037202176
346232864 5698771510037665280  <----
3366459424 5698771510038193664
2091784224 5698771510332259072
817109024 5698771510332816128  <-----
3837335584 5698771510333344512
2562660384 5698771510339882240
1287985184 5698771510340411392
13309984 5698771510340939776 <-------
3033536544 5698771510348048896
1758861344 5698771510348577280
484186144 5698771510349228800
3504412704 5698771510632804864
2229737504 5698771510633441792
955062304 5698771510634390272
3975288864 5698771510638858496
2700613664 5698771510639347712
1425938464 5698771510642663168
134486304 5698771510643387136
3154712864 5698771510643808768
```

I am running the following commands in bash.

```
gnuplot

reset
set terminal png

set xdata time
set timefmt "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H:%M"
set xlabel "time"

set ylabel "highest seq number"
set yrange [0:65535]

set title "seq number over time"
set key reverse Left outside
set grid

set style data linespoints

plot "print_1012720" using 1:2 title "Flow 1"
```

It gives garbage in my shell. I suspect that it is the spacing between the columns that is causing this. However if I correct the spacing then the file is correctly plotted. Any clue how this can be rectified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your main problem is that you are not setting an output.  After your `set terminal` command you should set an output file, otherwise gnuplot will spit out the .png to your terminal, which looks like gibberish.  Try putting the following in a file (saved as 'plot.plt' for instance) and then run `gnuplot plot.plt` at the bash command line.

```
set terminal png 
set output 'output.png'

set xdata time
set timefmt "%s"
set format x "%H:%M"
set xlabel "time"

set ylabel "highest seq number"

set title "seq number over time"
set key reverse Left outside
set grid

set style data linespoints

plot "print_1012720.txt" using 1:2 title "Flow 1"
```

Creating a plot file this way will save you a lot of time typing at the gnuplot command line.

A couple of other comments:

1) You set your yrange to be 0:65535 when your y values from the datafile are much larger.

2) It looks like you are trying to extract a time in UNIX format from the first column in your datafile.  For this you would want the line `set timefmt '%s'` as I have above.  However, the time data in the data file appear to be all over the place, as do the y data.

3) You do not need the `reset` command at the beginning, since running gnuplot this way will create a new instance of gnuplot, so there will be nothing to reset.

4) You also had 'print_1012720' without the '.txt' extension; I'm not sure this was an error on your part.